# validate a string only if the condition meets in regex C#

Tags: c#, regex, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a Regex for a string where following rule is applied

1. I need to validate the string only if first 1-3 characters (it can be 1 char,2 char or 3 char ) are numeric  and after that it has a '/' symbol character
2. If the 1st condition meets then i need to check whether the characters after that '/' should be any one of the following chars only ('ADD.','MOD.'), if not it should fail
3. If the 1st condition doesnot meets then it should not validate the string.

i tried with this regex but i am not able to get the solution.

```
(?=^[0-9]{1,3}[/]{1})^[0-9]{1,3}[/]{1}[(ADD.|MOD.)]{4}|(.*)
```

the condition doesnot fails when i validate a string - `'123/testing'` it should fail

Please let me know what i am missing.

Kind Regards,
D.Mahesh

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use this regex:

```
^\d{0,3}/(ADD\.|MOD\.)
```

Like this:

```
string regex = @"^\d{0,3}/(ADD\.|MOD\.)";
```

Comment: hi amit just modified the question

Comment: the starting char can be any numeric char and it can be 1/ or 34/ or 980/ if is satisifies this condition then i need to check rest of characters otherwise i donot need to check rest of the characters in the string

Comment: thnx for ur prompt reply and help i tried ur regex with the following examples but still no luck -123/test
6/MOD.1test
126/MOD.1test
60/MOD.1test
abc/MOD.1test
60MOD.1test
6/MOD1
12ts/ADD.       i am testing with regexlib tester in the above example s all are valid string only 123/test is an invalid string

Comment: i tried with regex still no results i think somewhere i am making mistake in using conditional regex